# How to check if IIS Compression with HTTPS/SSL is working?

Tags: iis, https, compression

I've setup a website for IIS compression, but it doesn't appear to be working for HTTPS, just HTTP. Is there something that needs to be configured to get this to work, or does this not work in IIS? What options are there?

UPDATE: According to [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/http-compression-for-web-applications/) the compression is occurring before the encryption. If compression is occurring for SSL requests, where do I see it?

UPDATE2: I went back to the metabase.xml file and discovered that the changes I made were gone. Here's what I had:

```
HcDynamicCompressionLevel="9"
    HcFileExtensions="htm
        html
        js
        css
        txt"
    HcOnDemandCompLevel="10"
    HcPriority="1"
    HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
        dll
        aspx
        exe"
```

I'm wondering if the in-memory metabase overwrote the changes I made before I was able to run IISRESET /RESTART??

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how IIS works but I believe that compression gets applied at the end. If that is the case, then it won't work well with encrypted data, which has random-like characteristics. However, it may still be possible to compress your data manually in your application before handing it off to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

The compression should work fine with both normal and ssl traffic, setting it up in IIS can be somewhat tricky, it's often not enough to just toggle the checkbox since it will only compress certain filetypes per default.

[IIS Compression](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d52ff289-94d3-4085-bc4e-24eb4f312e0e.mspx?mfr=true)

Is your SSL site is pointing to the same application in IIS ? Are you using anything like an SSL accelerator hardware with your server ?

First try the form to the right on the port80 site to see if IIS is compressing: http://www.port80software.com/

Comment: It's coming back as uncompressed with HTTPS, but compressed with HTTP